# Does guest information stay saved?

Tags: macbook-pro

If I am using a friends computer as a GUEST and then sign out. Can my information still be seen by the owner of the computer or does it get deleted???
Like I did t want them to see what I was researching ect ??

Answer (score 2):

No, guest data is not permanent.

From [Apple docs](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22029?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

> Files created by a guest are stored in a temporary folder, but this folder and its contents are deleted when the guest logs out.

Comment: Unless that's on a FileVault drive or SSD, I don't think that would make it forensically clean, but would be more than enough to hide it from the casual observer.